# Real Analytic function .

Tags: derivatives, power-series, analytic-functions, singularity

Let $f$ a real analytic function at $x=a$ i.e. having power series expansion about the point $x=a$.  Can we say about radius of convergent of power series ? Like its equal to the distance form $a$ to nearest singularity of $f$  in complex analysis. I have a  example $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ which is analytic at every point of $\mathbb R$ but it’s power series about $x=0$ has radius of convergent $1$. So is there any results to estimate it’s radius of convergent? As in this example I think it is related to complex function $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$. Thank you.

Comment: You have provided an answer yourself: it is the distance from $0$ to $\pm i$, which are the nearest singularities.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but these are not singularity in real axis . I means these are not singularity of given real function.

Comment: Indeed. But their exists affects the radius of convergence anyway.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so I should always do like this example i.e.  convert in complex and check ?

Comment: Yes, that what you should do.

Comment: One needs to be careful. There are smooth functions like $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\le0$. The power series expansion of $f(x)$ at $x=-1$ has infinite radius of convergence but only equals the original function in a radius $1$ around $x=-1$. The problem at $x=0$ is obvious but it's not exactly a "singularity".

Comment: @GregMartin my above discussion is not valid ?

Comment: I agree with Greg's objection, but there is no need for $e^{-1/x^2}$.  If $f$ is real analytic at $a$, then the Taylor series of $f$ converges to $f$ on some neighborhood of $a$ (that is the definition).  But it could happen that the Taylor series converges on a set larger than that neighborhood, but disagrees with $f$ somewhere on that larger set.